# Can't find an issue with my code. Error: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

```
df_tracks = pd.read_csv('fma_metadata/tracks.csv',index_col=0, header=[0, 1])
df_tracks = df_tracks[df_tracks['set']['subset'] == 'small']
df_features = pd.read_csv('fma_metadata/features.csv', index_col=0, header=[0, 1, 2])

idx_small = df_tracks['set']['subset'] == 'small'
idx_train = df_tracks['set', 'split'] == 'training'
idx_val = df_tracks['set', 'split'] == 'validation'
idx_test = df_tracks['set', 'split'] == 'test'

y_train = df_tracks.loc[idx_train, ('track', 'genre_top')]
y_test = df_tracks.loc[idx_test, ('track', 'genre_top')]

X_train = df_features.loc[idx_small & idx_train, 'mfcc']
X_test = df_features.loc[idx_small & idx_test, 'mfcc']
```

I am getting an `IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer` with the last two lines. I hope you can help me solve this issue.

Comment: You almost certainly want `idx_small and idx_train`.  The `&` operator in Python is bitwise.

Comment: Errros is expected because filter `df_features` by another masks from `df_tracks`, it failed if not same index  valuse in both DataFrames.

Comment: Thank you, I now understand the issue. Is there any way to get only the index values that exist in `df_features`? using `idx_small` and `idx_train`.